# Convert Date to Milliseconds in Java

Tags: java, date, milliseconds

I need to convert a Date to its corresponding Milliseconds format.I am using `getTime()` method of **`Date`** class in Java for this. But the milliseond generated is not of my actual date. It is one day less than my date. For eg,

I have `22-Nov-2014`. If I convert this date to milliseconds  format then `1,416,594,600,000` is generated. Actually this value corresponds to `21-Nov-2014`.

Please help me to get an exact milliseconds value corresponds to a `Date` in java.

Comment: Could you show us the actual code that you're using to do your conversion, along with what output you're expecting, and what output you're actually getting?  Also, what timezone you're in.

Answer (score 10):

1416594600000 corresponds to 2014-11-21T18:30:00Z. In other words, 6.30pm on November 21st 2014 *in UTC*. [Epoch Converter](http://epochconverter.com) is a great resource for checking things like that.

Now, a `Date` object doesn't have any time zone information itself. It just represents a point in time. It sounds like your "22-Nov-2014" value was probably midnight in the *local* time zone (India?). If you are generating values from lots of different time zones and you don't store which time zone goes with which value, you've essentially lost some information here.

If you're trying to *just* represent a date (rather than a point in time) but you have to store it as a milliseconds-since-the-unix-epoch value, it probably makes sense to store midnight of that date *in UTC*, although you should also make it very clear that that's what you're doing. If you can, you should store the value in some way that makes it more obvious it's a date - such as using a `DATE` field in a database. Date and time work is often really not as hard as we fear it to be *if* you know exactly what data you're modelling, and make that very clear everywhere in your code.

One way to make things clearer is to use a good date/time API which allows you to represent more kinds of data than `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` do. [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) is good for this, and Java 8 has the new `java.time.*` API. I'd strongly advise you to move to one of those as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.of( 2014 , Month.NOVEMBER , 22 )
         .atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of ( "Asia/Kolkata" ) )
         .toInstant()
         .toEpochMilli()
```

## Details

The [Answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24817587/642706) is correct and wise.

Here is some example code using java.time classes.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

You can specify a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2014 , Month.NOVEMBER , 22 );
```

> ld.toString(): 2014-11-22

## `ZonedDateTime`

You desire a count-of-milliseconds-since-epoch. I do *not* recommend using a count-from-epoch for handling date-time. But if you insist, here we go.

A count-from-epoch of milliseconds means we need a date *and* a time-of-day. We have a date. I assume you want the first moment of the day as the time-of-day. Do *not* assume this time is `00:00:00`. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) may mean the day starts at some other time such as `01:00:00`. Let java.time determine that first moment by generating a `ZonedDateTime` object from a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of ( 2014 , Month.NOVEMBER , 22 );
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of ( "Asia/Kolkata" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay ( z );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2014-11-22T00:00+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

## `Instant`

You can extract an `Instant` if desired. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction). A developer should think of UTC as the *One True Time*, and *not* think about their own parochial time zone while working.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant ();
```

> instant.toString(): 2014-11-21T18:30:00Z

From the instant we can ask for a count of milliseconds since epoch. Be aware this involves **data-loss** as any nanoseconds will be truncated to milliseconds.

```
long epochMillis = instant.toEpochMilli();
```

## `java.util.Date`

I suggest avoiding the legacy date-time classes. But if you *must*, you can convert. Look to new methods added to the old classes like [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).

```
java.util.Date utilDate = java.util.Date.from( instant );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).